# CBOR decode the attestationObject

Tags: php, webauthn, cbor

I'm trying to implement webauthn and getting tripped up at the CBOR decoding part. The webauthn method returns a byte array which has to be CBOR decoded to get a json object. Since I have to send this byte array to the php server I convert it into base64 encoding to send it via ajax.

Once I receive it, in PHP I perform a base64_decode and pass it into the [CBOR decoder](https://github.com/2tvenom/CBOREncode/).

```
$attestationDecoded = base64_decode($attestationString);
$attestationObject = \CBOR\CBOREncoder::decode($attestationDecoded);
```

This gives me an output like this

```
Array
(
    [fmt] => none
    [attStmt] => Array
        (
        )

    [authData] => CBOR\Types\CBORByteString Object
        (
            [byte_string:CBOR\Types\CBORByteString:private] => I�
���ht4��dv`[�䮹��2Ǚ\���cE
�X$Jh���%��j���.�a{��g�r,*�~����
        )
)
```

The authData is where the information I need is but I can't figure out how to convert this into a usable JSON string or php array. For context, [this is the guide](https://webauthn.guide/#registration) I'm following and if you search for the heading "Parsing the authenticator data", that is what I need to do in php but I can't find any resource on how to do this in php.

I've tried base64decode, mb_convert_encoding, passing it again into the CBOR decoder etc but nothing works.

Here's a sample base64 encoded string so you can test out yourself.

```
$attestationString = 'o2NmbXRkbm9uZWdhdHRTdG10oGhhdXRoRGF0YVkBZ0mWDeWIDoxodDQXD2R2YFuP5K65ooYyx5lc87qDHZdjRQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACCLYg9301sjLI-9num_RMORAERiSadbMUKGX8LpnLRGRaQBAwM5AQAgWQEA6zHIUbPhjXt6mCLjOnFbL5k6oV6fw00u8XYSm3Zy3BBClX_BGugmndYAmRhU8qwcCzBGvd3OYccYIVX10vvSanAnBToh-uiGlniCFpA_dH6dFUWhK4A1w6STOOR54KOVe-lo98jIKHbQHChxyqu9iF1D5pMYvAtnKdJDGCWZ7v_etxjmk1GMbIi1aeZ1jlSv6L1rxmZNZjtqsQ5kms532JxgawNfv1sPFMItoVYCB2tVOSrS1Y6voGsHTrXAj-4BdQpEtiAss8GFlm6nDZ-dvW9wK7HeJE8yStUkVKzdkAh0AWSImNCEsMD-iaLAVq3bm9C0HER3L90f2igb1MVdmyFDAQAB';
```

Comment: You get attestation format `none`, are you sure that is a valid attestation?

Comment: Attestation is optional and I chose not to have it so 'none' is expected.

Answer (score 1):

Note that there are provisions in WebAuthn to save you some of this bother: https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn-2/#sctn-public-key-easy

But, taking your attestation string, it parses into the following CBOR structure:

{"fmt": "none", "attStmt": {}, "authData": h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}

The `authData` there is a binary format: https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn-2/#authenticator-data

Pulling it apart:

- RP ID hash: 49960de5880e8c687434170f6476605b8fe4aeb9a28632c7995cf3ba831d9763
- flags: 0x45
- Signature counter: zero
- AAGUID: 00000000000000000000000000000000
- Credential ID length: 0x20
- Credential ID: 8b620f77d35b232c8fbd9ee9bf44c39100446249a75b3142865fc2e99cb44645

The the remainder is CBOR data that decodes to

{1: 3, 3: -257, -1: h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h'010001'}

(Unusually an RSA key.)

Comment: You decoded it but how? Can you post the code? And it must be php code as it is to be done on the server side. BTW is it safe to have this info you posted in public domain? Its from my actual computer.

Comment: The link to `authenticator-data` in the answer kinda details how it works, `Authenticator-data` has binary data and sometimes ends with more cbor encoded data. So to actually parse it you might need to do some manual steps there. The data posted is safe, it is only the public part of the key. I posted a answer to a very similar question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77953764/google-titan-key-attestation-data/77969318#77969318 that might detail the data a bit more.